# Why does the Cauchy Theorem for triangle fail in this case?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(x+iy)=x^2+yi$. Find the integral $\int_{L} f(z) dz$, where $L$
>   is the union of the two straight line paths: starting from $-i$ to $2+5i$ and then to $5i$.

**My attempt:**

Note that if we include the straight line path $L^*$from $5i$ to $-i$, then we get a triangle. $f$ is analytic on the whole complex plane, then by the Cauchy Theorem for triangle, $$\int_{\partial \Delta}f(z)dz=0.$$
It follows that the required path integral is $$\int_{L} f(z) dz = \int_{\partial \Delta}f(z)dz - \int_{L^*} f(z) dz=- \int_{L^*} f(z) dz.$$
Now, parametrize $L^*$ by $z(t)=(5-6t)i$, for $0\leq t\leq 1$. Direct computation shows that the last integral is $-12i$.

However, when I try to compute the integral directly, i.e. parametrize $L$ and then integrate $f$, I get $-12+2i$, which is the solution.

So why does Cauchy Theorem not applicable in this case? Or did I make a mistake?

Comment: Unless you made a typo in your question, $f(x+iy)=x^2+yi$ is *not* analytic (holomorphic).

Comment: @MartinR : Oh no! Because it is of class $C^1$ but it does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equation?

Comment: $f$ is not $C^1$ because $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,0)/x = 0$ and  $\lim_{y\to 0} f(0,y)/(iy) = 1$

Comment: @stity: $f$ is even $C^\infty$ (as a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$).

Comment: @MartinR $f$ is not even differentiable at 0, $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)/z$ does not exist

Comment: @stity: We are talking about different things. $f$ is differentiable as a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$, but $f$ is not *complex differentiable*.

Comment: @MartinR yes I send the comment before I saw your edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Cauchy Integral theorem does not apply here because $f(x+iy)=x^2+yi$
is *not* an analytic (holomorphic) function. The partial derivatives
of all order exist, but the the Cauchy-Riemann equations are only
satisfied in one single point.